# What's the easiest way to return a recordset from a PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I simply have a table that contains a list of countries and their ISO country codes.  I'm wrapping the query in a stored procedure (aka function) such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_countries(
                    ) RETURNS setof record AS $$
        SELECT country_code, country_name FROM country_codes
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

I know that I can define a TYPE and then loop through the recordset like a cursor, but IIRC there's a better way to do this under newer versions of PostgreSQL (I'm using 8.4.3) but I'm pulling my hair out trying to remember.

---

Edit:

This works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_countries(
                    ) RETURNS setof country_codes AS $$
        SELECT country_code, country_name FROM country_codes
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Note the "RETURNS setof [table name]". But it doesn't seem to be the most flexible.  It falls apart if I attempt to return a join of several tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring the tuple structure of a record in PL/pgSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907563/declaring-the-tuple-structure-of-a-record-in-pl-pgsql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use output parameters, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_countries(country_code OUT text, country_name OUT text)
RETURNS setof record
AS $$ SELECT country_code, country_name FROM country_codes $$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 16):

There is also the option of using `RETURNS TABLE(...)` (as described [in the PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-TABLE)), which I personally prefer:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_countries()
RETURNS TABLE(
    country_code text,
    country_name text
)
AS $$
    SELECT country_code, country_name FROM country_codes
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

This is effectively the same as using `SETOF tablename`, but declares the table structure inline instead of referencing an existing object, so joins and such will still work.