# Declaring the tuple structure of a record in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I can't find anything in the PostgreSQL documentation that shows how to declare a record, or row, while declaring the tuple structure at the same time. If you don't define you tuple structure you get the error "The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate".

This is what I'm doing now, which works fine, but there must be a better way to do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS TABLE (
    "a" integer,
    "b" varchar
  ) AS $$
DECLARE r record;
BEGIN

CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_t (
    "a" integer,
    "b" varchar
);
-- Define the tuple structure of r by SELECTing an empty row into it.
-- Is there a more straight-forward way of doing this?
SELECT * INTO r
FROM tmp_t;

-- Now I can assign values to the record.
r.a := at.something FROM "another_table" at
       WHERE at.some_id = 1;

-- A related question is - how do I return the single record 'r' from
-- this function?
-- This works:
RETURN QUERY
SELECT * FROM tmp_t;

-- But this doesn't:
RETURN r;
-- ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set

END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are mixing the [syntax for returning `SETOF` values with syntax for returning a single row or value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

> -- A related question is - how do I return the single record 'r' from

When you declare a function with `RETURNS TABLE`, you have to use `RETURN NEXT` in the body to return a row (or scalar value). And if you want to use a `record` variable with that it **has to match** the return type. Refer to the code examples further down.

#### Return a single value or row

If you just want to return a single row, there is *no need* for a record of undefined type. @Kevin already demonstrated two ways. I'll add a simplified version with `OUT` parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(OUT a integer, OUT b text)
   AS
$func$
BEGIN
   a := ...;
   b := ...;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You don't even need to add `RETURN;` in the function body, the value of the declared `OUT` parameters will be returned automatically at the end of the function - `NULL` for any parameter that has not been assigned.
And you don't need to declare `RETURNS RECORD` because that's already clear from the `OUT` parameters.

#### Return a set of rows

If you actually want to return *multiple* rows (including the possibility for 0 or 1 row), you can define the return type as `RETURNS` ...

- `SETOF some_type`, where `some_type` can be any registered scalar or composite type.
- `TABLE (col1 type1, col2 type2)` - an ad-hoc row type definition.
- `SETOF record` plus `OUT` parameters to define column names andtypes.
  100% equivalent to `RETURNS TABLE`.
- `SETOF record` without further definition. But then the returned rows are **undefined** and you need to include a column definition list with every call (see example).

[The manual about the record type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-RECORDS):

> Record variables are similar to row-type variables, but they have **no
>   predefined structure.** They take on the actual row structure of the
>   row they are assigned during a SELECT or FOR command.

There is more, *read* the manual.

You *can* use a record variable without assigning a defined type, you *can* even return such undefined records:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    r := (1::int, 'foo'::text); RETURN NEXT r; -- works with undefined record
    r := (2::int, 'bar'::text); RETURN NEXT r;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM my_func() AS x(a int, b text);
```

But this is **very unwieldy** as you have to provide the column definition list with every call. It can generally be replaced with something more elegant:

- If you know the type at time of function creation, declare it right away (`RETURNS TABLE` or friends).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS SETOF tbl_or_type AS
$func$
DECLARE
    r tbl_or_type;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO tbl_or_type  * FROM tbl WHERE id = 10;
    RETURN NEXT r;  -- type matches

    SELECT INTO tbl_or_type  * FROM tbl WHERE id = 12;
    RETURN NEXT r;

    -- Or simpler:
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 14;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- If you know the type *at time of the function call*, there are more elegant ways using [polymorphic types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC):
  [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557)

Your question is unclear as to what you need exactly.

Comment: Great answer. Think I am right in concluding that there is no way to dynamically define the output table structure within a function unless providing the column definition list within the call?

Comment: @Stev_k: Mostly, yes. But there is one more option with ***polymorphic types***. Check the last link in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740256/refactor-a-pl-pgsql-function-to-return-the-output-of-various-select-queries/11751557#11751557 (last chapter).

Answer (score 4):

There might be some way that avoids the explicit type declaration, but offhand the best I can come up with is:

```
CREATE TYPE my_func_return AS (
    a integer,
    b varchar
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  RETURNS my_func_return AS $$
DECLARE
  r my_func_return;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1, 'one' INTO r.a, r.b;
  RETURN r;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Oh, I almost forgot the simplest way to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func2(out a int, out b text)
  RETURNS RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT 1, 'one' INTO a, b;
  RETURN;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to use `OUT` parameters rather than a record. If iteratively building a set of records (a table) use `RETURN NEXT`. If generating from a query, use `RETURN QUERY`. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/955289/398670

and:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html
  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html
  http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/129-Use-of-OUT-and-INOUT-Parameters.html

Think:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(OUT a integer, OUT b varchar) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Assign a and b, RETURN NEXT, repeat. when done, RETURN.
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```