# Strange 'Unknown table' when performing plpgsql script

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I have one same table in several schemas from PostgreSQL database server. I need
execute one query like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION git_search() RETURNS SETOF git_log AS $$
DECLARE
sch name;
BEGIN
    FOREACH sch IN 
     select schema_name from information_schema.schemata where schema_name not in ('pg_toast','pg_temp_1','pg_toast_temp_1','pg_catalog','information_schema') 
    LOOP 
        qry := 'select count(*) from'|| quote_ident(sch) || '.git_log gl where gl.author_contributor_id = 17';      
    RETURN QUERY qry; 
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;    
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

select git_search();
```

but I have the error:

> ERROR:  "git_log" type not exists
>   SQL state: 42704

The `git_log` table is unknown in the first line of script. (clause `CREATE`)

Anybody can help me?

There are more than 100 schemas where I need perform the query that is adjusted for this situation. What is the best way to do this? Where I can create the function for this purpose?

Comment: Presumably `git_log` is not a known type in the schema where the function is being created.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There are more than 100 schemas where i need perform the query that is adjusted for this situation. What is the best way to do this? Where i can create the function for this purpose?

Comment: You need to define a type that is either a string (for the way the function is currently written) or an integer (assuming you really mean return query execute).

Comment: Sorry to say, but Gordon's comments are *completely incorrect*. The schema you are creating the function in has nothing to do with anything here. You don't have to define more types, certainly not `a type that is either a string .. or an integer`. Please ignore that. I posted a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thank you for help, now the script is functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name would serve just fine as composite type name, because a composite type of the same name (schema-qualified) is created with every table automatically.

The **immediate cause of the error**: none of your tables (actually the associated composite type of the same name) named `git_log` can be found in the current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777), so the type name cannot be resolved.

Since you are operating with many schemas and many instances of tables called `git_log`, you need to be unambiguous and schema-qualify the table name. Just pick any *one* of your tables in one of the schemas, they all share the same layout:

But the rest of your function isn't going to work either. It's not a "plpgsql script", but a function definition. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION git_search()
  RETURNS SETOF one_schema.git_log AS
$func$
DECLARE
   sch text;
BEGIN
   FOR sch IN 
      SELECT schema_name
      FROM   information_schema.schemata
      WHERE  schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
      AND    schema_name <> 'information_schema'
      ORDER  BY schema_name
   LOOP 
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
         'SELECT count(*)
          FROM   %I.git_log
          WHERE  author_contributor_id = 17', sch);      
   END LOOP;
END  
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM git_search();
```

#### Major points

- [`FOREACH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) is for looping though arrays, you need a [`FOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) loop.
- You need dynamic SQL. [Search for examples with more explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]%20[dynamic-sql]%20execute%20format)
- Call the function with `SELECT * FROM`.
- Related answer (one of many):

  - [Passing column names dynamically for a record variable in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159768/passing-column-names-dynamically-for-a-record-variable-in-postgresql/18162632#18162632)

Comment: In the final code, my function returns 'SETOF record' instead 'one_schema.git_log'
and the context of the call I had adjust to:

SELECT * FROM git_search () AS foo (val bigint);

Comment: @TarcisioM.: I hardly ever return anonymous records with `RETURNS SETOF record`. Postgres can not decompose the records and you have to provide a column definition list with every call. [If you know the return type, declare it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907563/declaring-the-tuple-structure-of-a-record-in-pl-pgsql/11911949#11911949) Also, [if you have your answer, please accept it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)