# postgresql function timestamp parameter

Tags: postgresql, function, parameters, timestamp

This is my first function.  The select query works well when executed manually fwith fixed constants.  But within my fucntion, the parameters gets wronly interpreted.

Basically, i'm trying to replace the timestamp with function parameters.

```
-- this my mananual query.  it works fine.
select  sum(least(end_time,'2017-05-16 11:30:00')- greatest(start_time,'2017-05-16 10:30:00')) as duration,
    from c_trunk 
    where (start_time < '2017-05-16 11:30:00') and (end_time > '2017-05-16 10:30:00')
    and trunk < 20

-- this is my bogus function with the select that calls it at the end. 
create function trunk_trafficD (p1 timestamp, p2 timestamp)
    returns boolean as $$
begin
select  sum(least(end_time,p2)- greatest(start_time,p1)) as duration,
    count(call_id), device as "system", trunk as "trunk" 
    from c_trunk 
    where (start_time < p2) and (end_time > p1)
    and trunk < 20
    and (device = 1 or device = 4 or device = 3)
return true;
end; $$
language PLPGSQL;

select trunk_trafficD('2017-05-16 10:30:00','2017-05-16 11:30:00');
```

Comment: what you mean  `wrongly interpreted.` ??

Comment: btw you can use `AND  device IN (1,3,4)` instead chainning those `OR`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the easiest way to return a recordset from a PostgreSQL stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036093/whats-the-easiest-way-to-return-a-recordset-from-a-postgresql-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the error message, but in PL/pgSQL you must use

```
SELECT expr1, expr2, ...
  INTO var1, var2, ...
FROM ...
```

Or you use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT` if you want to discard the result.

Comment: You could add, right now OP function always return `TRUE` when you probably want return a dataset.

Comment: there are no errors.  the manual command execute in 10 seconds while  the function runs over my 44 million records.  I think the "where" clause is not working properly in the fucntion because parameters are not properly interpreted.

Comment: Use the [`auto_explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) module with `auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0` and `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` to get the plans for the SQL statements in the function into the PostgreSQL log. You can add these plans to the question, that will make the case clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to_timestamp() finction for your parametrs